# Is there a way to execute two commands in parallel and get the that ends first?

Tags: sh, dd

I'm trying to modify code found here https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/17924/detect-idle-state-power-off-screen so it could monitor two js inputs at the same time. How can I achieve this?

I'm struggling with this part

```
inputActive=$(
    timeout ${inputWindow} \
        dd \
            if=/dev/inputs/js0 \
            of=/dev/null \
            count=${inputCount} \
            >/dev/null 2>&1;
    echo $?
)

if [ ${inputActive} -eq 0 ]; then
```

so if there is activity on js0 it will return 0.
I would like to have something like

```
inputActive=$(
    (
        timeout ${inputWindow} \
            dd \
                if=/dev/inputs/js0 \
                of=/dev/null \
                count=${inputCount} \
                >/dev/null 2>&1;
        echo $?
    );
    (
        timeout ${inputWindow} \
            dd \
                if=/dev/inputs/js1 \
                of=/dev/null \
                count=${inputCount} \
                >/dev/null 2>&1;
        echo $?
    )
)
```

once activity is discovered on any input it should go further and not wait till all tasks are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run both commands in the background and use `wait -n` to wait until either one finishes. (Get rid of the whole `inputActive=$(...; echo $?)` business. It's not doing anything useful.)

```
timeout "$inputWindow" dd if=/dev/inputs/js0 of=/dev/null count="$inputCount" &> /dev/null &
timeout "$inputWindow" dd if=/dev/inputs/js1 of=/dev/null count="$inputCount" &> /dev/null &
wait -n
```

If you want to check for success you can use `wait` directly in an `if` statement:

```
if wait -n; then
    echo "one of them succeeded"
else
    echo "one of them failed" >&2
fi
```

By the way, you could use `read` in place of `timeout` and `dd`. `read -N` will read a certain number of characters and `read -t` sets a timeout.

```
read -N "$inputCount" -t "$inputWindow" < /dev/inputs/js0 &
read -N "$inputCount" -t "$inputWindow" < /dev/inputs/js1 &
wait -n
```

Comment: thank you again John. I managed to test it and can confirm that it works. Except the second option. In Raspbian when I use `read -N "$inputCount" -t "$inputWindow" < /dev/input/js0 &` I've got and error saying `-bash: read: read error: 0: Invalid argument` but as I already wrote earlier the first option suits my needs :).

Comment: @AdamKiryluk I get the same error message from bash, but it works with busybox ash. However, the busybox lacks the -n option. zsh is also not wait -n friendly. #JohnKugelman, does it still work for you, which shell (and version) are you using?